# Angular $scope object showing $scope.data but when I try to use it, the says undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this controller that takes info from a service.

When I return the data to the controller I am using $scope to let the view have the data.

I have a few console.logs and the ones inside the then function work fine. However outside, the $scope object that gets logged has a .data but when I try to console.log it, it comes back as an empty object.

Is there something in my code that's wrong?

```
(function() {

  angular
    .module("eplApp")
    .controller("tableCtrl", TableController);

  TableController.$inject = ['httpService', "$scope"];

  function TableController(service, $scope) {
    var apiTableUrl = "http://api.football-data.org/v1/soccerseasons/426/leagueTable";
    $scope.data = {};

    service.getListFromUrl(apiTableUrl).then(function(data) {
      $scope.data = data;
      console.log($scope);
      console.log($scope.data);
    });
    console.log($scope);
    console.log($scope.data);
  }
})();
```

Comment: At that time the promise from `service.getListFromUrl` hasn't resolved so it didn't set `$scope.data = data;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular is asynchronous, that's why you can't console it outside service response

Try to print the data this way..

```
function TableController(service, $scope) {
  $scope.data = {};

  service.getListFromUrl(apiTableUrl).then(function(data) {
    $scope.data = data;
    printData();
  });

  function printData() {
    console.log($scope.data);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That does indeed now print the data to the console. But what if I want to use that data in the view? Can I just reference it straight from the getList... function or do I have to do something special?